# Differentiability of certain integral

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Is the function $$f(x,y,z)=\int_0^x\int_0^y\int_0^z\int_0^x\int_0^y\int_0^z\frac{dx_1 \, dy_1 \, dz_1 \, dx_2 \, dy_2 \, dz_2}{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2+(z_1-z_2)^2}$$
$C^2$-differentiable in all its variables?

Comment: Yeah and it seems to be $C^1$